# Web To Case using Webservices/Sites

Tags: apex, visualforce, webservices

I have to  implement Web To Case.

I have thought of two options for the same using Sites or Web Services. I have queries related to the same.

If I implement it using Web To Case, then, How can I use the automatically generated code for web to case using sites. 
I know how to configure using HTML pages. Now, I want to use sites of force.com

With Webservices, which one is good REST/SOAP etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web to Case doesn't use REST or SOAP API; it's a simple HTML form with a POST submit. You can paste the code verbatim into a Visualforce page, expose it on your Site, and it will be behave as any other form; you can capture cases automatically.

If you want to use the REST or SOAP API, which you can, you wouldn't be using Web to Case, which is a simple POST to the server. Web to Case would take just minutes to set up on a Site (minus any styling you need to make it your own design). Using web services, you could be manually creating the records via the API.

If you chose to go with web services, you may as well just create a Visualforce page and have it designed like any other Visualforce page; there's no need to leverage the API just to submit a case through Sites. Note that you can only "create" cases, not update them, using the Sites technology.

Answer (score -1):

To add to the above comment, There is a way to use Web to Case from a backend tech such as C#. However, you would need to create a Form Content Post, not a usual HTTP Post

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/201506)